# How to select all arrows of a certain colour in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a slide with a complex diagram made of many arrows of different colours. I would like to change the style of the arrows which are blue. I would have to click on each arrow to select them and then apply the new style. Is there a way to select all the arrows which share the same style/color ?

Answer (score 4):

Not directly possible in PowerPoint.  If you're fairly good with VBA, you could write some code to do the job.

If you only need to do this once in a while, it's probably not worth the effort, but if you'll be changing these things regularly, there are a couple of addins that might help.

I have an add-in called ShapeStyles that lets you "memorize" the style of one shape then apply it to others and also set the shape's style as "sticky", meaning that when you redefine the style, all of the similarly styled shapes in the whole presentation get set to the new style.

The add-in itself is commercial but the free demo allows you to create up to five styles.  That might be all you need.  http://www.pptools.com/shapestyles/

There's also a free Selection Manager add-in
http://www.pptools.com/FAQ00135.htm

It lets you select any number of shapes then save the selection as a named selection, one you can recall (ie, re-select) at any time.

Comment: Hi Steve, is it still not possible natively in PowerPoint to select things with matching properties, e.g. formatting or color, across slides? Or alternatively, create something like a "cross-slide spanning layer" where you can put things, and then show or hide that "layer"?

Comment: @David.P Still not possible, I'm afraid. In fact, you can't select anything across multiple slides. It might be possible to do what you're after with a few custom layouts, though. Put the stuff to be shown on one layout, then remove them from a duplicate layout and assign the appropriate layout to relevant slides.

Answer (score 1):

PowerPoint has no option for selecting objects by color or shape.

A commercial extension that has this capability is
[PPT Productivity add-in for PowerPoint](https://pptproductivity.com/powerpoint-addin/create-faster).

Unfortunately, this tool is part of their Power Tools, which costs
$149 per user/year, with 30-days trial.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three approaches (A,B,C) which can be taken:

### A) Change theme colors

Powerpoint uses "theme colors" which can be easily changed. In most cases this will work, especially if you create your PPT carefully from the beginning.
[image]

There are 10 basic colors, plus lighter/darker variations of those. If you have used standard colors, go to solution (B).

**Customize/Change your colors** (see also [this detailed description](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-your-own-theme-in-powerpoint-83e68627-2c17-454a-9fd8-62deb81951a6) to understand more about themes)

- Go to View -> Slide master
- Select Colors -> customize colors. This opens the "create new theme colors" dialogue. The colours should match those of your current active theme.
  [image: image from support.microsoft.com]
- Now, change the color(s) as needed. Give your theme colors a name such as "MyColors". *Please note that this will change the colors both of shapes and text*.
- If you later want to change a specific color, go back to the slide master view, and in the "colors" drop-down right-click on the "MyColors" palette and select "Edit". Re-change the colos(s) as needed.
- You can also create several theme colors, and switch between them as needed.

**NOTE:** To make all elements of one color "disappear", change that color to the same color as the slide background.

### B) Search-replace by macro

If solution (A) doesn't work for you, you'll either have to use a third-party plugin, or  write a macro. [This SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/968770/714576) has a script for text color replace: it should be fairly easy to adapt it to object color replace.

If you need help adapting your macro, ask on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

### C) Hide/Show objects by Macro - independent from color

Specifically to answer the Bounty. Taken from [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66054741/powerpoint-hide-show-grouped-objects-in-entire-presentation).

The idea is, that you will create grouped objects on each slide, only for the elements that you want to show / hide.

Then, [create a macro](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-macro-in-powerpoint-5b07aff6-4dc9-462f-8fc9-66b4c5344e7e) which shows/hides only the grouped objects in the whole presentation, using the following code:

```
Sub Numbers()

Dim sld As Slide

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides

sld.Shapes("Shape Group").Visible = msoTriStateToggle

Next sld

End Sub
```